# How does hdparm calculate spin-down times?

Tags: hard-disk, hdparm

I have been trying various options with hdparm, like setting the spin-down time to 5 minutes with
`hdparm -S 60` and setting the APM to 1, but I end up getting a spin-down in less than 5 seconds... How do these values combine to end up in a spin-down time?

According to Western Digital support:

> Thank you for contacting Western Digital Customer Service and Support.
>   My name is Esther.
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience, I will be more than glad to assist
>   you.  The WD Black internal hard drive doesn't have a utility that can
>   be used to adjust the drive's spin down time.
>
> Unfortunately, since you're using a third party application (HDPARM)
>   to adjust the drive's spin down, we're unable to provide any
>   information on how to properly set the parameters on the utility. We
>   would recommend contacting the manufacturer of the application.
>
> If you have any further questions, please reply to this email and we
>   will be happy to assist you further.

I need to get some more useful information from my drive manufacturer about this.

Answer (score 2):

The spindown time `-S 60` is equal to 5s*60 and corresponds to 300s. The APM levels `-B 1-127` (permitting spindown) and `-B 128-254` (not permitting shutdown) [are more or less passed directly to the disk](https://superuser.com/a/558622/105023) and `hdparm` doesn't do any further computation on those values.

The exact behaviour of those values is unspecified and left to the drive manufacturer. Therefore `hdparm` can't document what they do.

Comment: Okay Marco, anything to say about my recent edit?